# How to make menus more responsive in Marlin 1.1.9

Tags: marlin, full-graphic-smart-controller

I have an AM8 with an MKS GEN 1.4 board with a Bowden extruder at the moment.

What I would like to do is to make my menus a bit more responsive, similar to what the guy at Lokster Space has done with ver 1.1.5 of Marlin with a tutorial how to do so. I've been through the file `ultralcd.cpp` but nothing matches what the tutorial is telling you to change.

The following link is the details for the upgrade: [How to make the Marlin menus more responsive on Anet A8](http://lokspace.eu/how-to-make-the-marlin-menus-more-responsive-on-anet-a8/)

Could anyone please help with my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly, it's no longer necessary in a [recent Marlin version](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/pull/8179), already the `inline bool handle_adc_keypad()` function from [ultralcd.cpp](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/bugfix-1.1.x/Marlin/ultralcd.cpp) has implemented a smaller (100 ms) time delay. You could lower the value of `#define ADC_MIN_KEY_DELAY 100` to `#define ADC_MIN_KEY_DELAY 50` to see if that has any effect.

Also, look for `next_button_update_ms = now + 300;` (4 instances) which employs a 300 ms time delay after buttons are pressed. Try lowering the 300 ms time delay.